# Google Analytics Demographics data missing

Tags: google-analytics

I've installed the tracking code from Google (the updated one, for demographics data), already validated the code and it worked, also enabled it in analytics settings. Problem is there is no data at all, and it's been set up for a week now. When I validated the code analytics said it'll be a day until I see data.

Any idea what's going wrong?

All other data is fine, just demographics missing.

Comment: Just to comment, I'm having a similar problem (can't see the Data, and can't validate after updating the code...). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032543/enable-demographics-and-interest-reports-in-classical-analytics

Answer (score 0):

These data won't be showed if you don't have enough users.  Can it be the case?

> Data thresholds
>   Thresholds are applied to prevent anyone viewing a report from inferring the demographics or interests of individual users. When a report contains Age, Gender, or Interest Category (as a primary or secondary dimension, or as part of an applied segment), a threshold may be applied and some data may be withheld from the report. For example, if there are fewer than N instances of Gender=male in a report, then data for the male value may be withheld.
>   These thresholds are system defined, and you cannot adjust them.
>   If a threshold has been applied to a report, you will see a notice below the report title.

[About Demographics and Interests](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en)