# Enable Demographics and Interest Reports in Classical Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

From a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968210/enable-demographics-and-interests-reports-in-universal-analytics) I've come to know that I can't enable Demographics and Interest Reports with Universal Analytics tracking code. So I've created a new **property** for my account using **Classical Analytics**.

I've also set **Enable Demographics and Interest Reports** to **ON** under Property Settings and uploaded the tracking code to the desired site (it is a Facebook Application hosted on GAE if that matters, [website link](https://jm-sfcb.appspot.com)).

As adviced by Google I've changed my tracking code to use DoubleClick instead of Analytics:

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://')
   + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
```

As far as I can tell, everything is configured as expected and my tracking id is receiving data.

Still, when I try to access any of the desired Demographic and Interested reports It says that my tracking code can't be validated. This is really weird since, as stated above, my code is already using **dc.js**.

[image: Tracking code message]

If i try to click on the Validate tracking code button it basically tells me the same thing again:

[image: After validation message]

So, am I missing something? Are we supposed to click Skip Validation?

**p.s.:** I've been struggling to get Demographics and Interest Reports to work for over a week (and yes, this is getting very frustrating...). Any help is highly appreciated.

---

### Update

It is now possible to Enable Demographics and Interest Reports also in Universal Analytics [check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23225754/664577)).

Comment: Skipping validation worked for me (in my case the Code did not validate because it was implemented via the Google Tag Manager). I don't think there is harm in trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data should show up in your reports soon (usually couple hours). Following up on Ishara's answer, I just wanted to stress that there is a **requirement to update your website policy** according to [these instructions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2700409):

> If you change your Analytics tracking code to support Display
>   Advertising, you are required to notify your visitors by disclosing
>   the following information in your privacy policy:
>
> - The Google Analytics features you've implemented based on Display Advertising (e.g., Remarketing, Google Display Network Impression
>     Reporting, the DoubleClick Campaign Manager integration, or Google
>     Analytics Demographics and Interest Reporting).
> - Visitors can opt-out of Google Analytics for Display Advertising and customize Google Display Network ads using the Ads Settings.

Comment: 2 Days and still no data. There is a yellow message "Some data in this report may have been removed when a threshold was applied. Learn more". But I'm having hundreds of visitors... Could you please take a look at the tracking code? https://jm-sfcb.appspot.com/

Comment: Anthony, I can see that the data is being sent to Analytics and that you use doubleclick cookies / dc.js. So everything setup-wise should be OK, so I did some digging and found this:
t is extremely important to know that this data is not available for every single user, so usually the reports will be based in a subset of users. In addition, some data in the reports may be removed when thresholds are applied to prevent inferring the identity of an individual user.

Comment: Is it possible that your visitors are limiting the use of their personal data?

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2954071?hl=en&ref_topic=2799375

Comment: Hi Petr, thanks for the analysis. I'm still not receiving data for the age and interest reports. Maybe some users are blocking the personal data, but between hundreds I don't think that all of them are blocking.

Comment: Data finally started flowing. Thank you ;)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly could you expand on what specifically fixed the issue?

Comment: Hello @Jesse, nothing really, it just took some (unusual high amount of) time for this warning to go off, eventually reports just begin to work. Recently, since Google introduced support for Universal Analytics, I've also updated my tracking code (check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23225754/664577)).

Answer (score 1):

did you Enable display advertiser features .

" Enable Demographics and Interest Reports in the Admin interface: click on Admin (top-right orange navigation), then on "Property Settings", then on the checkbox below the Demographics and Interest section "

Comment: Ishare, yes it is set to **ON**. I've pressed the Skip Validation button... No data so far, guess I will have to wait a couple of days.

Comment: I also pressed Skip Validation button by mistake. Have you found any solution @AnthonyAccioly

Comment: Hi Umar, it started working after about 48 hours. More recently I have also updated to Universal Analytics (check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23225754/664577)).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'xdomain.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Please try the above code and Enable display advertiser features. Lets see after that.

Comment: Hi yusuf, the problem has already been resolved. Anyway I think that there is a delay of way more than 48 hours for this specific data to become available (or at least it did for me).

Answer (score -2):

**Demographics doesnt work with Google Sites - yet**

If your using google sites to have your website (which I am unfortunatly) your limited to your access to your source code, so you cant make the necessary adjustments to add the demographics (blacks and whites and girls and boys to your site) data to your analytics, you only get the Original analytics (visits per day etc.).

[My complaint on the Forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/sites/DDiudxwWkSk/D1CnVQYaA6EJ)

To enable demographics data, you need to put in that piece of code, well you cant edit google sites to add that code in. Also your "site manager" in google site only has 1 option related to Google Analytics, either turn it off or turn it on, and put in your UA_code.

Google Please fix this, why does your free and amazing Demographics Analytics service not included with your Google Sites package, kind of embrassing on your part (big guy)